# Calling a wcf service method from another a wcf service: good, bad or should be avoided if possible?

Tags: performance, wcf

Is calling a wcf service method from another a wcf service good, bad or should be avoided if possible?

Another question..
Is it better to encapsulate business logic in a single dll and then expose it thru a service or write the logic directly in a wcf service(without using any dlls/assemblies)

Comment: Just to further clarify the question.. I mean, calling a wcf service method that is hosted on another site/server

Answer (score 0):

You can call other WCF service methods directly but you will not get of the behaviors that WCF normally applies such as instancing and synchronization. It seems much cleaner to me to move logic that you want to share into a helper class. But basically you can call WCF methods like any other method (because they are just methods).

You can move code into a separate DLL if you want. But since that increases the complexity of the project there should be a good reason for that.